# How to get all terms for a Lucene field in Lucene 4

Tags: java, api, lucene

I'm trying to update my code from Lucene 3.4 to 4.1. I figured out the changes except one. I have code which needs to iterate over all term values for one field. In Lucene 3.1 there was an IndexReader#terms() method providing a TermEnum, which I could iterate over. This seems to have changed for Lucene 4.1 and even after several hours of search in the documentation I am not able to figure out how. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: I just moved the answer part to the answer you marked since it could be confusing and non-intuitive to search and find the answer in the question formulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please follow [Lucene 4 Migration guide](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/MIGRATE.html)::

> How you obtain the enums has changed. The primary entry point is the
>   `Fields` class. If you know your reader is a single segment reader, do
>   this:
>
> ```
> Fields fields = reader.Fields();
> if (fields != null) {
>   ...
> }
> ```
>
> If the reader might be multi-segment, you must do this:
>
> ```
> Fields fields = MultiFields.getFields(reader);
> if (fields != null) {
>   ...
> }
> ```
>
> The `fields` may be `null` (eg if the reader has no fields).
>
> Note that the `MultiFields` approach entails a performance hit on
>   `MultiReaders`, as it must merge terms/docs/positions on the fly. It's
>   generally better to instead get the sequential readers (use
>   `oal.util.ReaderUtil`) and then step through those readers yourself,
>   if you can (this is how Lucene drives searches).
>
> If you pass a `SegmentReader` to `MultiFields.fields` it will simply
>   return `reader.fields()`, so there is no performance hit in that case.
>
> Once you have a non-null Fields you can do this:
>
> ```
> Terms terms = fields.terms("field");
> if (terms != null) {
>   ...
> }
> ```
>
> The `terms` may be `null` (eg if the field does not exist).
>
> Once you have a non-`null` terms you can get an enum like this:
>
> ```
> TermsEnum termsEnum = terms.iterator();
> ```
>
> The returned `TermsEnum` will not be null.
>
> You can then `.next()` through the `TermsEnum`

Comment: Great to mention the migration guide, but I think your answer would be a lot more useful if you could post here the part that is relevant to the question and what you suggest to do.

Comment: I just added the relevant part to my question above.