# Finding number of unique terms over multiple fields

Tags: java, lucene

I need to find number (or list) of unique terms *over a combination of two or more fields* in `Lucene-Java`. I am using `Java` libraries for `Lucene 4.1.0`. I checked questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910008/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-unique-terms-from-a-specific-field-in-lucene) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290980/how-to-get-all-terms-for-a-lucene-field-in-lucene-4), but they discuss finding list of unique terms from a **single** (specific) field, or over **all** the fields (no subset).

For example, I am interested in `number(unique(height, gender))` rather than `number(unique(height))`, or `number(unique(gender))`.

Given the data:

```
height,gender
1,M
2,F
3,M
3,F
4,M
4,F
```

`number(unique(height))` is 4, `number(unique(gender))` is 2 and `number(unique(gender,height))` is 6.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: so, what this query means? number(unique(height, gender))

Comment: @Mysterion - it should return number of unique pairs of (height, gender) from the index.

Comment: Let's take example of 2 countries and 3 states in each country. C1, C2 - it's countries; S1, S2, S3 (in C1), S4, S5, S6 (in C2) - are states. What is the right answer and why? Please update your question with correct example, that will clear for everybody to understand it

Comment: Then list all this six, and please explain why you couldn't count (C1, S6) since first value is from field country, second value is from field state and it's unique over all possible pairs for my example

Comment: 6. Other combinations such as (C2,S1) will not appear in the data. It is clear from the notation `number(unique(height, gender))`.

Comment: @Mysterion - Only because you did not understand my question (although it was clear), that is no reason to down-vote my question.

Comment: you couldn't understand it clear. if to you it looks ok - it doesn't mean it's ok to all people. Also, when I ask you a question you answer always with the same - I need this, I said it there, but if you understand problem well - i'm pretty sure you should able to describe it to 5 year old kid, but you don't try to. i will give one last try. why (2,M) isn't unique in your terms? cause you don't have documents with that value?

Comment: Look, I will not post a question if it were as simple as multiplying counts from two fields. I have described it in the question, I have illustrated with an example, and here I am telling you again: I don't want to create fictitious combinations. If (2,M) does not appear in the data, I don't want to count it. I find it really immoral of you to down-vote a question only because I did not accept your answer earlier (which you posted without first understanding the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have predefined multiple fields then the simplest and quickest (in search terms) would be to index a combined field, i.e. heightGender (1.23:male). You can then just count the unique terms in this field, however this doesn't offer any flexibility at search time.

A more flexible approach would be to use facets (https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/facet/index.html). You would then constrain you query to each value of one field (e.g. Gender (male/female)) and retrieve all the values (and document counts) of the other field.

However if you do not have the ability to change the indexing process then you are left with doing a brute force search using Boolean queries to find the number of documents in the index for all combinations of the field values in which you are interested. I presume you are only counting combinations where the number of documents is non-zero.

It is worth noting that this question is exactly what Solr Pivot Facets address (http://lucidworks.com/blog/pivot-facets-inside-and-out/)

Comment: 1) Yes, facets are one way to look at it. However, that way, I will have to fetch counts/documents for each value in the first field and then add them. That sounds exhaustive. Doing this for 3 or more fields would again be problematic. I was looking for a better (faster) way.

2) This again sounds exhaustive. I would rather fetch all documents, get the fields I need and keep a set over those to automatically eliminate duplicates.

3) solr pivot facets sound interesting. I will take a look at it and see whether moving to solr is an option for me.

Thanks for taking time and answering.

Comment: And regarding predefined multiple fields - I do not have that priviledge. I can not know in advance, and can not save all possible 2^n combinations :-(

Comment: As faceting works on the indexes rather than documents I think you'll find it's quite fast. For my test data finding the document count for combinations of values for two fields, each with 1,000 values (so 1,000,000 combinations) takes around 7 seconds, which compares with around 4 seconds if I create a combined values field.

One caveat about using Solr Pivots, on the same test data performance is around 4 seconds. However for versions >= 4.10 there is an interesting feature which severely affects pivot performance (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-6803).

Comment: I see. Thanks for the details. I will mark this as accepted if I don't get anything better by tomorrow.